# what is the fastest way to assign data array items to range values

Tags: excel, vba, ado

I am developing an excel client to a SQL server data base.

When I select data from the data base to the client records are saved in arrays. These arrays are then "injected" into Excel sheets using an array of variant.

This technique is far faster than assigning individual cell values BUT seems to fail in some specific context.

When the data value is vbNullString the range cell corresponding to the item is not assigned. Worst if the first item is vbNullString, none of the items are saved to the range. 
My guess is that the vbNullString is translated to null as a variant and the variant array has the wrong dimension.

Is there any other explanation ?

For instance

```
ByRef loTable As ListObject,
ByRef sItems() As String
```

are parameters of a sub executing the following code where
loTable is an Excel Table (ListObject) and  sItems the data I want to assign to the range of the Excel Table loTable

```
Dim lCount as Long
Dim vItems() as Variant
lCount = UBound(sItems)-LBound(sItems)+1
'size vItems as a 2D array - required to fetch a range
If (lCount > 0) Then ReDim vItems(1 To lCount, 1 To 1)
'copy string to variant
Dim i As Integer
For i = LBound(sItems) To UBound(sItems)
    vItems(i, 1) = sItems(i)
Next i
Dim olrs As ListRows
Set olrs = loTable.ListRows
With loTable
    If (lCount > 0) Then
        If (Not (.DataBodyRange Is Nothing)) Then .DataBodyRange.Delete
        olrs.Add
        If (lCount = 1) Then
            olrs(olrs.Count).Range.Cells(1, 1).Value = sItems(LBound(sItems))
        Else
            .DataBodyRange.Resize(lCount, 1).Value = vItems
        End If
    Else
        .DataBodyRange.Delete
    End If
End With 'loTable
```

I come to the question : have you tried such a range (of a table) value assignment and how to cope with null items in an array for a fast assignment.
Looping over the array items and adding one by one just takes for ever.

Comment: I'm pretty confused by your setup. I'd use ADODB to get data from the SQL server. Execute your command to a `Recordset` and dump your data out using `GetRows` or `CopyFromRecordset`

Comment: so am i. I see there a direct solution to the problem. I ll try it out

Comment: Maybe consider deleting this question and asking a new one with your your new code

Comment: easier alternative might be Data tab > From Other Sources > From SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would something like this help?

```
'Declarations section
Private Const gsPROVIDER as String = [Provider]
Private Const gsDATA_SOURCE as String = [Source]
Private Const gsINITIAL_CATALOG as String = [Catalog]
Private Const gsUSER_ID as String = [User ID]
Private Const gsPASSWORD as String = [Password]

Private Sub Test
    Dim rsData As Object
    Dim sConnect As String
    Dim sSQL As String

    sConnect = "Provider=" & gsPROVIDER & _
               "Data Source=" & gsDATA_SOURCE & _
               "Initial Catalog=" & gsINITIAL_CATALOG & _
               "User ID=" & gsUSER_ID & _
               "Password=" & gsPASSWORD
    sSQL = 'SQL in a string

    Set rsData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsData.Open sSQL, sConnect

    If Not rsData.EOF Then
        Worksheets(1).ListObjects(loTable).DataBodyRange.CopyFromRecordset rsData
    Else
        MsgBox "No data found!", vbCritical, "Error!"
    End If

    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: this one does the job (compared to using GetRows and saving data into a buffer then applying CopyFromRecordset). How do you handle the case where .DataBodyRange is Nothing (empty table). check first add an item then execute the statement you gave ?

Comment: @pascalsautot You should be able to simply execute the statement and it will overwrite whatever is there. There is no need to even add the appropriate number of rows and columns. Just `CopyFromRecordset` to the upper left most cell in the table.

Comment: if the table is empty (row count=0) .DataBodyRange will be Nothing and Worksheets(1).ListObjects(loTable).DataBodyRange.CopyFromRecordset will raise an error

Comment: @pascalsautot Update your code. Hard to tell without looking at it. You shouldn't need an `IF` statement.

Comment: here is the piece of code before copying If (.DataBodyRange Is Nothing) Then loTable.ListRows.Add

Comment: @pascalsautot When you open the connection to your SQL query you only need to dump the data into the table. You don't need to test for anything or add listrows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159250/discussion-between-brian-and-pascal-sautot).